# <ol> <li> weird challenge - keep left margin

Tags: html, css

There is a huge html from which is use to generate pdf. There are a lot of sections with numered paragraphs. It looks like this:

```css
.list-number {
  float: left;
}

.list-content {
  padding-left: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="list-number">7.</div>
  <div class="list-content">
    Fanta</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number">8.</div>
  <div class="list-content">Coca Cola</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number">9.</div>
  <div class="list-content">
    Coca cola</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number">10.</div>
  <div class="list-content">Fanta</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number">11.</div>
  <div class="list-content">Sprite</div>
</div>
```

Now I have to add another section. The main difference is that it's dynamic list, so I have to use ol li tags. I did something like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ol>
```

The problem is with two digits number - in the div section there is no space after dot. How to make ol-li list to simulate same situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow... took me long enough to understand what were you asking... anyway, you can use a custom [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) instead of the list-style from the OL, and style it as needed.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: number;         
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  float:left;  width:20px; 
  counter-increment: number;            
  content: counter(number) ".";   
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ol>
```

Best part is you can adapt it for your current structure:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: number 7;
/*I set it at 7 for presentation purposes, most likely you'll want it at 0*/         
}

.list-number {
  float: left;
}

.list-content {
  padding-left: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
}


.list-number::before {
  counter-increment: number;            
  content: counter(number) ".";   
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="list-number"></div>
  <div class="list-content">Fanta</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number"></div>
  <div class="list-content">Coca Cola</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number"></div>
  <div class="list-content">Coca cola</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number"></div>
  <div class="list-content">Fanta</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="list-number"></div>
  <div class="list-content">Sprite</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Guy for helping. I'm sorry for not clear explanation :) It was really late in the night and I was really tired. Now, when I read my question I know what You mean ;) Anyway, I'll try again. 1) I can't touch other sections, they have to stay as is 2) Other sections have rigids numbers and text 3) My new section is diffrent, because I have to get the source from database, so some rows LI have tag VISIBLE.

Comment: 4) I used OL LI tags and was happy, that it's working. Then I noticed that there is a difference, that I struggle for a long time. 5) In the DIV section there is one-digit number, then dot, then space, then text, like: "1. text" "7. text". In two-digits case there is: number, then dot, then number, like: "21.text" "11.text" 6) Notice, that first number from two digit is just under the one digit number in DIV 7) In OL LI tags dot is always in the same place, digits are placed on the left from dot. 8) it's not about start numbering from 7 ;)

Comment: @szym17 Just edited my OL example, I think that's exactly what you want. But anyway, please re-read my comment... see my divs example, there are no hard coded numbers there, but it gets generated dynamically. You could add / delete items there and it will keep working fine. So you could as well use the code you already have for the new dynamic section, maybe in a wrapper so you can counter-reset and counter-increment without affecting the static sections at all

Comment: wow, it really works! Thanks very much, You save me nervous breakdown :) Really appreciate Your help! Now, I understand css better :)

Comment: @szym17 glad to help. If the answer works for you, remember to upvote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use start attribute

7. Fanta
8. Tea
9. Coca Cola
10. Fanta
11. Tea
12. Coca Cola
13. Fanta
14. Tea
15. Coca Cola
16. Fanta
17. Tea

```
<ol start="7">
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what he's asking

Comment: @FacundoCorradini I don't know, maybe! But if you do then what is he asking for. Explain it so we can help him/her.

Comment: I **think** he wants to have no space between the dot on the counters and the start of the text. But I had to read it five times to understand, and still not sure